# Cordova 3.3 - fileSystem.root.fullPath returns "/" instead of full path

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

I had a piece of code working with Cordova 2.7. I upgraded my app to Cordova 3.3 along with upgrading all the custom plugins I developed.

I was successfully able to get the full absolute path of the Documents directory on iOS with Cordova 2.7, but with Cordova 3.3 it just returns `/` for the fullPath

Here is my code:

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    alert("entered gotFS: " + fileSystem.root.fullPath);
}
```

I tested this on iPad Simulator 7.0 (which was giving correct results with Cordova 2.7)

Although, I can get the path with other methods, I would prefer to use the Cordova API.

The API documentation doesn't mention anything about this. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi @Mahendra , did You solved this problem?, I had same problem with Cordova 3.3 and there is not documentation. I was debugging the app and the url on file Download is not matching and returning nil

Comment: @Schwertfisch, Yes I solved it. I looked into the source code and see that fullPath is initialized with `/`. By any chance are you comfortable with objective c? IF not, I can post my answer

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Now It's working, I thought there was an issue with File Plugin because it was returning cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ and I added + / by error. cdvfile://localhost/persistent// but @Divesh Salian is right because fullPath is not working on C 3.3 now uses fileSystem.root.toURL().
Thank You guys

Comment: Mahendra, I would very much appreciate if you would post your answer. I am similarly stuck. You solution may move me past it. Thx.

Comment: @Ric Sorry for the delay in getting back, I posted my answer. Hope that helps. Let me know if you need any inputs or something is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since few users requested for my answer, here is how I managed to get the `Documents` directory path:

```
var documentsDirectoryPath = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
documentsDirectoryPath = documentsDirectoryPath.substring("file://".length);
documentsDirectoryPath = documentsDirectoryPath.substring(0, documentsDirectoryPath.indexOf("/<<YOUR_APP_NAME>>.app/www/index.html"));
documentsDirectoryPath += "/Documents";
```

Remember to replace **YOUR_APP_NAME** with your app's name

Answer (score 8):

try changing `fullpath` to `toURL()` and test

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
  alert("entered gotFS: " + fileSystem.root.toURL());
}
```

Comment: +1, this is more reliable than @Mahendra's answer since depending on the development approach `window.location.href` might not represent the device path.

Comment: I tested only Cordova 3.7, they changed it to a first level `nativeURL` property

Comment: If your current code expects old cordova 2 `fileSystem.fullPath` format like `/../data/Containers/Data/Application/FE01.../Documents` for the path then you might also need to clear off first 7 letters `file://` from the returned URL. Use `(filesystem.root.toURL()).substring(7);`